# How to trigger a click event on specific x and y position of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger

By this code I get coordinates by I don't know how to trigger these
`(X = 1043, Y = 73)` coordinates on body load.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="rating"></div>

<div id="status"> </div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".rating").click(function(){
  // X = 1043 
  // Y = 73
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = coords;
}); 
});

</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('.rating').on('page:click', function(e) {
  var coords = "X coords: " + e.clientX + ", Y coords: " + e.clientY,
  aim = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  $(aim).click();
  console.log(aim);
  $('#status').text(coords);
  });
  var action = $.Event('page:click', {clientX: 1043, clientY: 70});
  $('.rating').trigger(action);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply trigger the click event like:

```
$(".rating").click(function(){
 // your code...
}).click() // triggers on first load/ready
```

Or,

```
.trigger('click')
```

Comment: thanx,  and where I set    X coordinate   = 1043  or  Y coordinate  = 73 coz i want to trigger on this coordinates

Comment: Ah, you're missing event parameter in your function :) `.click(function(event){`

Comment: You can't set coordinate to where you want to trigger the click. They are read only properties.